# Deserialization issue while linking two ArangoDB collection in ArrayList

Tags: java, arangodb, json-deserialization

I have two db collections `Agency & Program` where an `Agency` can have many `programs` and all the further concept implementation is using Programs only. So I have created two POJO

```
public class Agency implements Serializable {
    @DocumentField(DocumentField.Type.ID)
    private String agencyId;

    @DocumentField(DocumentField.Type.KEY)
    @SerializedName("AGENCYNAME")
    private String agencyName;

    @SerializedName("SHORTNAME")
    private String shortName;

    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = true)
    @SerializedName("PROGRAMS")
    private List<Program> programs;

    // Other fields with Getter & Setters
}


public class Program implements Serializable {

    @DocumentField(DocumentField.Type.ID)
    private String programId;

    @SerializedName("PROGRAMNAME")
    private String programName;

    @DocumentField(DocumentField.Type.KEY)
    @SerializedName("SHORTNAME")
    private String shortName;

    @SerializedName("AGENCY")
    private Agency agency;

    // Other fields with Getter & Setters
}
```

When I run `AQL : for a in AGENCY return merge(a, {PROGRAMS: (for p in PROGRAMS FILTER p.AGENCY == a._id return p)})`

I get following JSON

```
[
  {
    "AGENCYNAME": "Dummy Agency 1",
    "SHORTNAME": "DA1",
    "_id": "AGENCY/1062620",
    "_key": "1062620",
    "_rev": "_URnzj-C---",
    "PROGRAMS": [
      {
        "_key": "DA1DP1",
        "_id": "PROGRAMS/DA1DP1",
        "_rev": "_UQ6dGOG---",
        "AGENCY": "AGENCY/1062620",
        "PROGRAMNAME": "DA1 Dummy Program 1",
        "SHORTNAME": "DA1DP1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "AGENCYNAME": "Dummy Agency 2",
    "SHORTNAME": "DA2",
    "_id": "AGENCY/1062358",
    "_key": "1062358",
    "_rev": "_URnzj-C---",
    "PROGRAMS": [
      {
        "_key": "DA2DP1",
        "_id": "PROGRAMS/DA2DP1",
        "_rev": "_UQ6dGOG---",
        "AGENCY": "AGENCY/1062358",
        "PROGRAMNAME": "DA2 Dummy Program 1",
        "SHORTNAME": "DA2DP1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

When I run this query from `arangodb-java-driver 4.1` it throws an exception while deserialization
`com.arangodb.velocypack.exception.VPackValueTypeException: Expecting type OBJECT`

and if I comment these lines from Agency.java it works fine, But I need to have List in agency.

```
    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = true)
    @SerializedName("PROGRAMS")
    private List<Program> programs;
```

Is there a way to handle lists in such cases ?
Please suggest a way to overcome this..
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your POJO `Program` you have a field agency which is from type `Agency` but in the JSON you get from the DB this field is from type string. Change type `Agency` to `String` and your code works.

**update:**

To get the result from your query which fits into your current java bean, run:

`for a in AGENCY return merge(a, {PROGRAMS: (for p in PROGRAMS FILTER p.AGENCY == a._id return merge(p, {AGENCY: a}))})`

Comment: Yes, It works in that case, but I want to have a cross reference Agency in Program, else I will have to hit another AQL to get Agency and it will affect application in a too frequent manner. Is there any way of doing that ? without hitting so many AQLs for getting cross references ?